# how to show image in RunKit REPL (notebook)

Tags: node.js, image, runkit.com

I was trying to make a notebook from RunKit (nodeJS notebooks), while I'm trying to study this course, something alike to the Jupyter's python notebooks

any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, something like this

```js
const image_url = "https://static.platzi.com/media/user_upload/0_Im9v-j_Ik1s7BQyA-072fb555-1138-4c02-bb39-1a72b092cfc8.jpg"

return image_url
```

[image: img-runkit]